# Split String by char Character

Tags: c#, string

```
String stringToSplit = "hello#World#How#Are#You";
string[] tokens = stringToSplit.Split('#');
```

This is absolutely Fine.

but How can i get the "Anjali" from this

```
String stringToSplit = "hello 'Anjali', How Are You";
string[] tokens = stringToSplit.Split(' '); // What to put Here as it doesnt take ' character
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to do this

```
var tokens = Regex.Split(stringToSplit, @"'", RegexOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape the `'` character:

```
string[] tokens = stringToSplit.Split('\'');
```

I would recommend looking into regular expressions (see `Regex` class) for better ways to accomplish these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell if you're wanting just `'Anjali'` by itself, or you're wanting `'Anjali'` to be an element as part of the split.

So here is an approach using `Regex.Match()` to get just string in single quotes, and using `Regex.Split()` where strings in single quotes will be an element in the array result.

```
String stringToSplit = "hello 'Anjali', How Are You?  My name is 'John'";

Console.WriteLine("Regex.Match()");
for (Match match = Regex.Match(stringToSplit, "'(.*?)'"); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);    
}
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Regex.Split()");
string[] tokens = Regex.Split(stringToSplit, "'(.*?)'");
foreach (string token in tokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine(token);
}
```

Results:

```
Regex.Match()
Anjali
John

Regex.Split()
hello
Anjali
, How Are You?  My name is
John
```