# split python bytearray character by character

Tags: python, sockets, serialization

So, I've got some python code

```
string = "Python is interesting."
arr = bytearray(string, 'utf-8')
arr.split(b'\'')
```

which I adapted from [Split String by char Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481323/split-string-by-char-character)

but it returns a

```
[bytearray(b'Python is interesting.')]
```

I was hoping to split it byte-by-byte. The end goal is to pass this to a C++ boost wrapper which expects an array of bytes character-by-character. I'm using a bytearray because I'm actually working with sockets and for a given large message I want to accumulate them.

```
    expected_length = _get_obj_size(socket)
    running_length = 0
    accumulator = bytearray(b'')

    while running_length < expected_length:
        msg = socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if msg:
            running_length += len(msg)
            accumulator += msg
        logger.debug("Finished reading in payload")
```

^ the above isn't particularly relevant but I felt like it might be useful to show why I'm doing what I'm doing.

Comment: `arr.split(b'\'')` means split by single quote which your string doesn't contain.

Comment: do you need `list(arr)`?

Comment: Ahh, crap. I didn't mean to do that. I sort of blindly copied what the post suggested. In any case, does anyone have any suggestions on how to split the bytearray into a list of individual bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the hint from @Epsi95 what about:

```
[chr(x) for x in list(arr)]
```